# How to raise a Jython exception from Java?

Tags: java, exception, jython

I am writing a Java class to be used within the scope of a Jython session. How can I raise a Jython exception like a `TypeError` or `KeyError`?

I can't seem to find anything in the Jython API to do this. (or do I just handle things the normal Java way and `throw new TypeError()` assuming I can find the Jython TypeError class?

Comment: I believe you need to do the "java way". anyway, remember that, you are running python code on the jvm.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote. Jython is an odd beast, and just because you do something in Java doesn't mean it interacts with the Jython interpreter in the right way. In this case I was missing information that `Py.TypeError` was the right thing to use. There is *no documentation* on [`Py.TypeError`](http://www.jython.org/javadoc/org/python/core/Py.html#TypeError), just that it exists. What threw me off when I first read the Javadoc is that Py.TypeError is also a static object; I didn't see the Py.TypeError static method as well.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a regular throw of errors will work properly. For example:

```
throw Py.TypeError("list indices must be integers");
```